# Firebase orderBy not working (when the orderBy field is the same)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my firestore collection, I have 10 documents with the field `numberOfUsers`. This is set to `1` in all of them. When I try and do a startAfter query, nothing is returned in the second query. The first one (startAfter: {}) works fine, and it returns 3 documents, but then when `startAfter: documentSnapshot`, nothing is returned (no errors).

I know this is because I am orderingBy a field that is the same across all documents, as when I orderBy a different field which is different for all of them (timestamp), it works fine.

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Your code snippet could help. A lot. So please include your code with your question.

Comment: Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)